# PropertyChangedEventHandler is null

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

What I have is a simple wrapper around a class Vector3 (a 3-D vector provided by OpenTK) which implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.  I want to have three text boxes bound to this vector (x, y, and z coordinate).  My wrapper (CameraVector) looks like:

```
public class CameraVector : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private Vector3 m_vector;

    public CameraVector ()
        {
        m_vector = new Vector3 ();
        }

    public CameraVector (Vector3 vector)
        {
        m_vector = vector;
        }

    public CameraVector (float x, float y, float z)
        {
        m_vector = new Vector3 (x, y, z);
        }

    public String CoordX
        {
        get { return Convert.ToString (m_vector.X); }
        set 
            {
            if (CoordX != value)
                {
                m_vector.X = Convert.ToSingle (value);
                OnPropertyChanged (new PropertyChangedEventArgs ("CoordX"));
                }
            }
        }

    public String CoordY
        {
        get { return Convert.ToString (m_vector.Y); }
        set
            {
            if (CoordY != value)
                {
                m_vector.Y = Convert.ToSingle (value);
                OnPropertyChanged (new PropertyChangedEventArgs ("CoordY"));
                }
            }
        }

    public String CoordZ
        {
        get { return Convert.ToString (m_vector.Z); }
        set
            {
            if (CoordZ != value)
                {
                m_vector.Z = Convert.ToSingle (value);
                OnPropertyChanged (new PropertyChangedEventArgs ("CoordZ"));
                }
            }
        }

    public Vector3 Vector
        {
        get { return m_vector; }
        set 
            {
            CoordX = Convert.ToString (value.X);
            CoordY = Convert.ToString (value.Y);
            CoordZ = Convert.ToString (value.Z);
            }
        }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged (PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            {
            handler (this, e);
            }
        }
    }
```

This provides three properties for the TextBoxes to be bound to while allowing other areas of the application to just pass (and receive) a Vector3 directly.  In the containing form I have:

```
m_center = new CameraVector (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
txtCameraX.DataBindings.Add ("Text", m_center, "CoordX");
txtCameraY.DataBindings.Add ("Text", m_center, "CoordY");
txtCameraZ.DataBindings.Add ("Text", m_center, "CoordZ");
```

The issue is when I get into my OnPropertyChanged method, the event handler is null.  My understanding is that this is how the data binding is made aware of the change.  So, that being said, am I doing something wrong here?  I am VERY new to data binding in C# so any criticism is welcome.

EDIT: Per the below suggestion I have done this:

```
m_bindCenter.DataSource = m_center;
txtCameraX.DataBindings.Add ("Text", m_bindCenter, "CoordX", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
txtCameraY.DataBindings.Add ("Text", m_bindCenter, "CoordY", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
txtCameraZ.DataBindings.Add ("Text", m_bindCenter, "CoordZ", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Answer (score 0):

[BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx) does the hooking up of INotifyProperty changed handler (and BindingList raises ListChanged events for you automatically if a property in the list changes).

Create a BindingSource, sets its DataSource property to your m_center.

When you create your bindings, pass the BindingSource as your second argument, rather than m_center.

The [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) docs actually have an example. They use a BindingList, but it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: OK, the event handler is no longer null.  I don't know how I missed that in that example... I was definitely looking at that one.  Anyway, the handler executes but the TextBox is not updating.  I trapped the TextChanged event and it only gets called once upon initialization.  I did trace through to where the handler gets called however.  Any idea what I could look for here?  Or any additional info I could provide?  Thanks